# length and typeof == undefined being ignored, lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash, undefined

Hopefully, my codepen is clear enough, first time using it -  https://codepen.io/jsfo011/pen/GRojmpw

`notEmpty` is JSON from my database. I wrote a function to loop through it and find the row that matches a parameter, returning the value.

If my function can't find a matching row, I want to return `0`.

I figured what I had written would work, but I keep getting

`"jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'total_income' of undefined" "TypeError: Cannot read property 'total_income' of undefined`

But it seems to work fine when it does match.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `income` after filtering does not have a single value (empty list), `single[0]` is undefined. So, the following code was trying to access a property "total_income" of undefined

```
income[0]["total_income"]
```

You need to make sure that the property is accessed only if the parent object `income[0]` is valid.

One way to do this is by adding another check to make sure that `income` has at least a single value in the list before we access it like so:

```
if (income && income.length) {
  if (income[0]["total_income"] !== undefined) {
    return parseFloat(income[0]["total_income"]);
  }
}
```

The line checks to make sure that income is defined and has at least one value.

Output:

```
    Empty Data - 0
    Found - 1000
    Not found - 0
```

Hope this helps in understanding the issue.

Comment: use `if (income && income.length)`, no need to test for undefined and it will catch other flasey objects as well and any non zero length will pass as truthy.

Comment: @AdrianBrand: Thanks! Updated the code with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

why not just using `lodash.get( )` with default value `0`:

```
function calculate(data, income_type) {
        let income = _.filter(data, {'income_type': income_type});
        let incomeValue = _.get(income, '0.total_income', 0);
        return parseFloat(incomeValue);
    }
```